# Object of type "None" is not subscriptable error using dictionary get()

Tags: python, pyright

Seems like I cannot even understand the basics of Python....

```
 current_price: float = current_items.get(item)[0]
```

When running pyright I get the following error complaining about the above line.

```
  D:\Git\pvp\main.py:71:36 - error: Object of type "None" is not subscriptable (reportOptionalSubscript)
```

current_items is a dictionary of list of values and all I wanted to do was get the first item in the returned value. Type(current_items.get(item)[0]) gives me a float type and get() always returns the correct float value.

This code gives my desired result but clearly I need to code in a different way just not sure why.

[image]

Comment: `.get` is for when you’re not sure if the key exists; it will return `None` instead of throwing an error if it’s missing. You seem to be sure the key exists, so as a simplification of @MahboobNur’s answer, you can just do `current_items[item][0]`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. I have preceding code with a get which check for a key which may not exist. The code above executes when I am sure that the key DOES exist. Removing the get resolves the issue as clearly it is a bad smell using a get even if there is no chance for as null value. Makes sense really as it does not look at the data just the code so it would not know so takes the worst case scenario. If you post your answer I will flag it as answered and upvote (if I can) Mahboobs answer as it also helped.

Comment: If the key existed, then `current_items.get(item)` would not have returned None.  So it seems the key did not exist, and therefore `current_items[item]` will also fail (but with a different error message).

Comment: I ran two gets. The first was enclosed in an if similar to MahBoobs comment. This one pyright does not complain about. The following one, the one that I highlighted will always get a value, but because I incorrectly used a get, pyright assumed that there is a   possibility of a None/NULL otherwise why would I use a get, hence why it triggered the error. Quite fascinating that it makes that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the key exists like this

```
if item in current_items:
    current_price: float = current_items[item][0]
    # Rest of your code
else:
    # as per your logic codes
```

Comment: That's correct, but surely your time would be better spent on finding a duplicate with this information, and much more detail?

Answer (score 0):

`reportOptionalSubscript` indicates an attempt to subscript (index) a variable with an Optional type, which could be illustrated by the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/packages/pyright-internal/src/tests/samples/optional1.py#L47) from `pyright` tests:

```py
c = None
if 1:
    c = [3, 4, 5]

# If "reportOptionalSubscript" is enabled,
# this should generate an error.
c[2]
```

Dictionary's `get()` method may return `None`, and that triggers the inspection regardless of actual data.

The first solution as mentioned by @Ry- is to get rid of `get()` and use square brackets to access the value. `pyright` stays silent with:

```py
current_price: float = current_items[item][0]
```

It could also be a good habit to assume possibility of exceptions and reflect that in the code. Also useful while working with external data (e.g. `JSON`) directly (without `pydantic` or similar):

```py
try:
    current_price: float = current_items[item][0]
except (KeyError, TypeError, IndexError):
    pass  # or handle these exceptions
```

The second solution is to [suppress](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/comments.md#line-level-diagnostic-suppression) a false positive diagnostic on that specific line with `# type: ignore` or `# pyright: ignore`:

```py
try:
    # here despite all exceptions being handled pyright still raises an error
    # assuming this is a false positive - ignore it
    current_price: float = current_items.get(item)[0]  # pyright: ignore
except (TypeError, IndexError):
    pass
```